# Creating plugin in Dynamics 365 that working with Office 365 Outlook

Tags: email, office365, tracking, microsoft-dynamics

I'm new in creating plugins for Dynamics 365 and I'm serching for some advices how to complete my task.

I need to create plugin in Dynamics 365 that autotracks mails from our managers that send there emails from Office 365 Outlook(now they need to go directly to the mail and click button'Track' and new email will created in Dynamics 365).

With what I need to start to pick up emails with outlook and then create the same in Dynamics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an feature in dynamics 365 to automatically track emails messages to dynamics 365, please view below link to know more.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/set-an-option-to-automatically-track-incoming-outlook-email-in-dynamics-365-for-outlook.aspx